# Kronecker product between two tensors

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, multiplication

I have two tensor: x is 2-by-2-by-3, y is also 2-by-2-by-3. Define each frontal slice of tensor is x1 x2 x3,y1,y2,y3. xi or yi are 2-by-2 matrix. How can I do kronecker product between x and y in matlab? What I want to get is kron(x1,y1),kron(x2,y2),kron(x3,y3) in matlab simultaneously without any looping.

Comment: So in terms of MATLAB, you want to efficiently find a way to call `kron` three times: `kron(x1,y1); kron(x2,y2); kron(x3,y3);` for each pair of 2D slices that come from each tensor?  `kron` can only take in 2D matrices - I'm not sure how you can vectorize this without any loops.  Why is escaping loops so paramount for your application... especially if the tensors are so small?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be one approach -

```
%// Pre-processing part
[m,n,r] = size(x) %// Get size
N = m*n %// number of elements in one 3D slice

%// ------------- PART 1: Get indices for each 3D slice

%// Get the first mxm block of kron-corresponding indices and then add to
%// each such block for the indices corresponding to the kron multiplications
%// of each iteration
a1 = bsxfun(@plus,reshape([0:N-1]*N+1,m,m),permute([0:N-1],[1 3 2]))

%// Now, a1 is a 3D array, we need to make 2D array out of it.
%// So, concatenate along rows to make it a "slimish" 2D array
a2 = reshape(permute(a1,[1 3 2]),size(a1,1)*size(a1,3),[])

%// Cut after every N rows to make it a square 2D array.
%// These are the indices for each frontal tensor of kron muliplications
slice_idx = reshape(permute(reshape(a2,N,size(a2,1)/N,[]),[1 3 2]),N,N)

%// -------------  PART 2: Get kron equivalent output

%// Perform x:(Nx1) x y:(1xN) multiplications
vals = bsxfun(@times,reshape(x,m*n,1,r),reshape(y,1,m*n,r)) %//multiplications

%// Get indices for all 3D slices and then index into those multiplications
%// with these for the final kron equivalent output
all_idx=bsxfun(@plus,slice_idx,permute([0:r-1]*m*m*n*n,[1 3 2])) %//all indices
out = vals(all_idx) %// final output of kron equivalent multiplications
```

Comment: Oh, it's just 3 dimensions! Then I understand even less of your code :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Yup, there is a lot going on! Added comments.. :)

Comment: @Divakar. This is really amazing..... how can you be so familiar with bxsfun() in matlab?...... Thanks Divakar.

Comment: @meng Got addiction to it and rehabs won't take me! ;)

Comment: @Divakar. I will read your code carefully and try to solve this kind of index problem myself next time.

Comment: @Divakar, I found a more neat way to get a2 from a1. You can type:     a1_tensor = tensor(a1);
  a2 = tenmat(a1_tensor,[1,3],2);

Comment: @meng Is `tensor` a MATLAB function? I can't find it.

Comment: @Divakar, you need install a tensor_toolbox  written by Tamara Kolda

Comment: @meng Hmm I see, actually there could be more simplified codes between `a1` to `slice_idx`, but then to make more sense from understanding point of view, I kept them as they are now.

Answer (score 6):

This works for arbitrary sizes of `x` and `y`:

1. Build a 5D array `z`. The first two dimensions contain the products of combinations of rows of `x` and `y`; the next two contain the products of combinations of columns of `x` and `y`; and the fifth is the original third dimension.
2. That arrray is reshaped, collapsing dimensions first ant second on one hand, and third and fourth on the other hand, to produce the final result:

Code:

```
z = bsxfun(@times, permute(x, [4 1 5 2 3]), permute(y, [1 4 2 5 3]));  %// step 1
z = reshape(z, size(x,1)^2, size(x,2)^2, size(x,3));                   %//step 2
```

Comment: Wow, good job really! Compact code! You need to change `2*m` to `m^2` though and same for `n`.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Corrected. I think this is the first time I use `bsxfun`  with 5D :-) Normally 3D is enough

Comment: Congrats then! :) It's so much of fun !!

Comment: Yes. Definitely the funniest  function!